# Send email whit codeigniter MAMP

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am trying to send email using gmail with codeigniter, my account has the necessary permissions in fact it works with other applications, here I leave my code to see if they can help me, Thanks.

My library to send email inside Library folder:

```
private $support = "myemail@gmail.com";
private $CI;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('email');
}


public function Goemail($email)
{

    $mensaje = "Texto";

        $this->CI->email->from($this->support, 'Mynombre');
        $this->CI->email->to($email);  
        $this->CI->email->subject('Asunto');
        $this->CI->email->message($mensaje);    
        $this->CI->email->send();


}
```

My config file inside Applications/conf/email.php :

```
 $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
 $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
 $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
 $config['smtp_user'] = "myemail@gmail.com";
 $config['smtp_pass'] = "mypass";
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me, apparently in codeigniter 3 you have to put this line compulsory in the configuration file email.php

```
$config ['newline'] = "\r\n";
```